# c# WCF UPNP mapping router configuration

Tags: c#, wcf, ip, router, upnp

I have written a c# code to do a port mapping by Upnp to my router in order to make acessible a WCF service to the internet

the upnp script is here

```
                        object[] loObj = new object[] { "", port, "TCP", port, adresse_ip, true, "Custom Mapping", 0 };
                    lsService.InvokeAction("AddPortMapping", loObj);
```

the in-port is 87 and the out-port is 87 too

the mapping is sucessfully registred on my Netgear DGN1000 ( i can see it in the upnp table )

```
Actif   Protocole   Port Interne    Port Externe    Adresse IP
YES     TCP       87                  87              192.168.0.12
```

I can access to my webservice via localhst:87/servicemodelsamples/service  and via 
192.168.0.12:87/servicemodelsamples/service

but y can't acess via MY_PUBLIC_IP:87/servicemodelsamples/service  .

i have disactivated Windows 8 firewall

when i am using a manual rule that i have created in my router i works , but via upnp nerver

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Note that a portmapping doesn't mean that inbound traffic on that port is allowed too.

Port 87 is below 1000. Some (older) routers block inbound traffic to ports < 1000 by default regardless of undp

Check the rules on the router to allow inbound traffic (udp/tcp) on port 87